# Solaris: How to run a system command on top of awk and combine all output in a single line

Tags: awk, ls, ksh

Have this peculiar requirement to print files in a given directory in the below mentioned format

`filename1     <type of file>     owner     group`
`filename2     <type of file>     owner     group`
`$`

The separator between columns being a tab.

I have been able to write the following command but the output of `system` command introduces a new line which I wish to avoid

```
find . -type f | xargs -I{} ls -let {} | awk -F" " 'BEGIN{OFS="\t" ORS=":"} {cmd=sprintf("file \"%s\"", $10);system(cmd);print $3,$4}'| tr -s ':\t ' '\t'
```

The produces the output as follows
`filename1     <type of file>`
`owner     group    filename2     <type of file>`
`owner     group    $`

I understand that the `system` command is reposnsible for the new line which I wish to avoid - I used ORS for the same reason but no luck.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use piped I/O from a command in `awk` (at least `gawk`, I haven't tested this on Solaris):

```
find . -type f | xargs ls -l | awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } { command=sprintf("file \"%s\"", $9); command | getline type; close(command); print type, $3, $4 }' | tr ":" "\t"
```

If your `find` supports it you can simplify this with

```
find . -type f -ls | awk ...
```

There's a handy [resource on using `getline`](http://awk.info/?tip/getline) which covers a number of caveats (including not using `close()` as I had initially).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the great tip using readline.

Comment: Wanted to know, is there a way I can perform an if condition analysis on the output of the file command above?
Say, if the file output says that the file is an ELF executable, can I run ldd and display the output alongside?

Comment: If you have another question you should really ask a new question. Nevertheless, you can use `type` in the same way as any other variable, in particular in an `if` condition after `getline` (... `getline type; if (type ...) { ... }; print type, $3, $4`). Try it and see...

Comment: Realized that after running the original command you gave, without using `close`, I run into instances of "awk: line 0 (NR=252): too many open streams to getline onto "file "some filename here"" kind of issue.

Comment: Indeed, I'll update my answer.