# Running a command on first column using system() function on awk

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, gawk

I have the following code which I'm running to extract some ip addresses and count the unique of them. For example

```
./my_program | awk '/^10./{a[$1 FS $2]++ } END { for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' > some_file
```

The output that `some_file` contains is this i.e:

```
10.12.33.14 34
10.12.33.11 12
10.12.33.16 5
```

Now what I want is run `{system("dig +short -x " i)}` and append the out to the last column so the file then looks like

```
10.12.33.14 34  server1.rdns.domain.tld
10.12.33.11 12  server2.rdns.domain.tld
10.12.33.16 5   server3.rdns.domain.tld
```

Can I do this in one go and then pipe the output to a text file?

Thanks!

**Update1**

```
... END { for(i in a) cmd=sprintf("dig +short -x \"%s\"", $i); cmd | getline type; close(cmd);  printf("%s %s %s\n",i,a[i],type);
```

This is what ends in the output (stderr)

```
dig: '.in-addr.arpa.' is not a legal name (unexpected end of input)
```

This is what I see in the file

```
10.12.33.14 34
```

**Update2:**

```
    END { for(i in a) split(i,ip," ")
    cmd=sprintf("dig +short -x \"%s\"", ip[1]); cmd | getline type; close(cmd);
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n",ip[1],ip[2],a[i],type)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solaris: How to run a system command on top of awk and combine all output in a single line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201723/solaris-how-to-run-a-system-command-on-top-of-awk-and-combine-all-output-in-a-s)

Comment: @muru thanks for the comment. got a step closer but not entirely. I get now the following. See update

Comment: @muru sorry for confusing you. I didn't post the whole correct code but I now updated my question.  I am using an array as follow `a[$1 FS $2]++`  and when run `./my_program` the IP's are returned in this form: `10.12.33.14 34`  where `34` in this case is a port number. and the 3rd field is the count.

Comment: So you need to split `i` to get the IP, instead of using `$i`. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-split_0028_0029-function Or save the IP in another array.

Comment: @muru thanks for the link that really helped. So we narrowed the problem now. One remaining thig is that it is now showing just 1 line instead of many which was the case earlier. See update2

Comment: I'm not sure `dig` command returns a valid result for storing in the variable

Comment: You haven't grouped your commands in the for loop .`for (...) { ... }`.

Comment: @muru awesome muru!  You are a hero!  It now works. Please post these findings as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it!  Maybe this is just a bit different than the duplicate.

Comment: That's OK, Inian has posted a useful answer.

Comment: How is `a[$1 FS $2]++` with an FS of `" " ` related to getting a unique set of IP addresses in `a[]`? I think you may be making this task more complicated than it has to be. If you provide a sample of the input to the awk command that you want to use to generate the posted expected output then we can help you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `split()` function to split the IP/port combination and get the IP for using later in the `dig()` command.

```
END { 
  for(i in a) {
    split(i, ip)
    cmd=sprintf("dig +short -x \"%s\"", ip[1])
    (cmd | getline type) > 0 ? "" : type="notResolved"
    printf("%s %s %s\n",i,a[i],type);
    close(cmd)
  }
}
```

I've added a way to check the status of `dig` command and used the `?` ternary operator to update the value of type. For cases of failure you can add your own string (e.g `'notResolved'` in the above) and print the result.

Do note that using the `getline()` call in `awk` is not the same as using `system()` call. The type `cmd | getline var` makes use of pipes as if the `cmd` is run from the shell each call to `getline var` reads one line of output from the command. The `system()` command though provides no way to get the output of the command executed inside. You only have access to the exit code returned from the command ran inside.

P.S. Answer partially adopted from useful comments of [muru.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru)

Comment: Great. Thanks Inian. THis works a treat. Well that's what makes this community so awesome! Sharing pieces of code and making it work!  Cheers.

Comment: `type = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "notResolved" )` would be clearer. Took me a minute to figure out what the existing code was doing and then another to figure out if/how it'd actually work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

### Step 1:

```
./my_program | awk '/^10./{a[$1]++ } END { for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' | tee some_file | xargs -I{} dig +short -x {} > some_file2
```

### Step 2:

```
paste <(awk '{print $1}' some_file ) <(awk '{print $1}' some_file2 ) > result
```

You can remove `some_file` and `some_file2` if you wish. `rm some_file some_file2`

Comment: @Pushman thanks for sharing but I said I wanted to use the `system()` function of awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid using `awk` at all. A little slower (although using the same number of invocations of `dig`) but quite possibly more readable.

```
while read -r ip count
do
    printf "%s %s %s\n" "$ip" "$count" "$(dig +short -x "$ip" | xargs)"
done < ipaddresses.txt
```